# Unable to install opencv On Mac OSX 10.7.3 with XCode 4.2 using MacPort

Tags: opencv, macports

I'm trying to install opencv using MacPort. i try:

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port install opencv
```

and i retrieve:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for opencv
--->  Dependencies to be installed: dirac cppunit autoconf help2man p5.12-locale-gettext m4 automake libtool faac faad2 ffmpeg XviD apple-gcc42 gcc_select gmake lame libogg libsdl xorg-libXext pkgconfig glib2 xorg-libX11 xorg-bigreqsproto xorg-inputproto xorg-kbproto xorg-libXau xorg-xproto xorg-libXdmcp xorg-libxcb python27 db46 libedit python_select sqlite3 python27 xorg-libpthread-stubs xorg-xcb-proto libxml2 xorg-util-macros xorg-xcmiscproto xorg-xextproto xorg-xf86bigfontproto xorg-xtrans xorg-libXrandr xorg-randrproto xrender xorg-renderproto libtheora libvorbis libvpx yasm openjpeg jbigkit lcms2 jpeg tiff libpng schroedinger orc speex texi2html x264 jasper liboil
--->  Configuring p5.12-locale-gettext
Error: Target org.macports.configure returned: configure failure: shell command failed (see log for details)
Error: Failed to install p5.12-locale-gettext
Log for p5.12-locale-gettext is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_perl_p5-locale-gettext/p5.12-locale-gettext/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: dirac cppunit autoconf help2man p5.12-locale-gettext m4 automake libtool faac faad2 ffmpeg XviD apple-gcc42 gcc_select gmake lame libogg libsdl xorg-libXext pkgconfig glib2 xorg-libX11 xorg-bigreqsproto xorg-inputproto xorg-kbproto xorg-libXau xorg-xproto xorg-libXdmcp xorg-libxcb python27 db46 libedit python_select sqlite3 python27 xorg-libpthread-stubs xorg-xcb-proto libxml2 xorg-util-macros xorg-xcmiscproto xorg-xextproto xorg-xf86bigfontproto xorg-xtrans xorg-libXrandr xorg-randrproto xrender xorg-renderproto libtheora libvorbis libvpx yasm openjpeg jbigkit lcms2 jpeg tiff libpng schroedinger orc speex texi2html x264 jasper liboil
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

what could be the error? how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download

```
http://vislab.cs.vt.edu/~vislab/wiki/images/4/44/OpenCV2.0.dmg
```

and copy the folder inside `dmg` into the framework library..

Answer (score 1):

```
Error: Failed to install p5.12-locale-gettext
```

**Read the error messages carefully**, then open the log it suggests to find out what the problem really was:

> Log for p5.12-locale-gettext is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_perl_p5-locale-gettext/p5.12-locale-gettext/main.log

If you still can't solve the problem, then you can always **download OpenCV source code** and compile it on your Mac.